# Maven command line to exclude download from a list of remote repositories by names

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, nexus, remote-repository

sometimes my remote repositories are not accessible, so I would like to know if there's a Maven command line option to prevent download from a list of remote repositories **by names**, without modifying my `settings.xml` or `pom.xml`

I'm looking for something like: `mvn clean install --exclude-remote-repositories=foo-repository,bar-repository`

Notes:

- `--offline` is too much, since it prevents me to access the central repository
- I don't want to change my `settings.xml` or `pom.xml`

Comment: The question is why offline wouldn't work if you already built before than everything should be cached in your `$HOME/.m2/repository`... If you have issue you should use a repository manager to handle that...

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is what khmarbaise suggested: Install a Nexus or Artifactory and use it to cache the remote repositories.